# Unable to get Ruby Page-Object gives error "undefined method"

Tags: selenium, rubygems, tdd, cucumber

I am new to using `PageObject::PageFactory`.

I can’t get this simple scenario to work. Can someone Help me with this?

#### My Feature file

```
Feature: Find Pens

Scenario:
 Given a user goes to Amazon website
 When they search for “pens”
Then they are able to find “pens”
```

#### My Step_definition

```
Given(/^a user goes to Amazon website$/) do
 visit HomePage
 end

When(/^they search for “(.*?)”$/) do |page|
 on HomePage do
 page.look_pens
 end
 end

Then(/^they are able to find “(.*?)”$/) do |arg1|
 pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
 end
```

#### Page Object file

QUESTION: Is it right to put this file in Support folder or should this be living elsewhere?

```
class HomePage
 include PageObject

page_url(‘http://www.amazon.co.uk’)

text_field(:name, :id=> ‘twotabsearchtextbox’) #:id is the web-element from the actual webpage. Should this be something else?
 button(:search, :value=>’Go’)

def look_pens(name,search)
 self.name = pens
 self.search
 end
 end
```

The `Given` part when run with `Cucumber-SeleniumWebdriver` does open the **Amazon browser**, but after that gives the following error for the `When` part

#### The Error

```
p.rb:1
 When they search for “pens” # features/step_definitions/buy_pens_ste
 p.rb:5
 undefined method `look_pens’ for “pens”:String (NoMethodError)
 ./features/step_definitions/buy_pens_step.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in ‘
./features/step_definitions/buy_pens_step.rb:6:in `/^they search for “(.*?
 )”$/’
features\buy_pens.feature:5:in `When they search for “pens”‘
```

#### My `env.rb` in the support folder contains:

```
require ‘page-object’
require ‘selenium-webdriver’
require ‘page-object/page_factory’

Before do
 @browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:firefox)
 end

After do
 @browser.close
 end

World(PageObject::PageFactory)
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically page object files are maintained in a separate folder that is at the same level as the features directory. You will need to use additional require statements so that Ruby knows that they are located in that folder.

Re the error: Looks like the compiler is having difficulty recognizing that look_pens is a method of the HomePage class. Try moving the |page| from the end of the When step def to the second line, so that it looks like code below.

```
When(/^they search for “(.*?)”$/) do
 on HomePage do |page|
  page.look_pens
 end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I did make the change you suggested to the When part but now it gives the following error: 

You can implement step definitions for undefined steps with these snippets:

When(/^they search for "(.*?)"$/) do |arg1|
  pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end

Comment: Also, I think the step_definition knows about the page object file because that is where it is picking the HomePage from.

Comment: I am still stuck with this. Tried both the things mentioned in the comments above. Any other ideas?